# Does transferring applications in Heroku also transfer add-ons?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a NodeJS application hosted on Heroku with the `Papertrail`, `mLab MongoDB` and `SendGrid` add-ons. I want to transfer the entire application, associated billing etc. to a different Heroku account, so my question is: would transferring the application also transfer the add-ons (and their respective billing) to the recipient account? If not, is there a way to do it? Please let me know if I should provide more info. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will transfer everything in the app, including the add-ons which will then be billed to the new owner.